# Rspec test for a Die's number of sides failing

Tags: ruby, rspec

Heys guys i am beginner in `rspec` Can anybody help me with this problem.
and my test `returns the number of sides that the die possesses` fail,what i am doing wrong??

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'die'

describe Die do
  describe '#initialize' do
    it 'expects a single argument' do
      expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq 1
    end

    it 'raises ArgumentError if sides are < 1' do
      expect {
        Die.new(-1)
      }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)

      expect {
        Die.new(0)
      }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
    end
  end


  describe 'Instance method' do
    before(:each) do
      @sides = rand(50)
      @die = Die.new(@sides)
    end
    context '#num_of_sides' do
      it 'expects method to have no arguments' do
        expect(Die.instance_method(:num_of_sides).arity).to eq 0
      end
      it 'returns the number of sides that the die possesses' do
        expect(@die.num_of_sides).to eq @sides
      end
    end
    context "#roll" do
      it 'expects roll method to have no arguments' do
        expect(Die.instance_method(:roll).arity).to eq 0
      end
      it "returns a random number between 1 and number_of_sides" do
        rolls = Array.new(10000) {@die.roll}.uniq.sort
        possible_values = (1..@sides).to_a
        expect(rolls).to eq possible_values
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Ruby Die Class:**

```
class Die
  def initialize(sides)
    raise ArgumentError if sides < 1
  end

  def num_of_sides(sides=nil)
    if sides!=nil
      Random.rand(50)
    else
      0
    end
  end

  def roll()
  end
end
```

> Output: 6 examples, 2 failures, 4 passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not yet implemented the `Die` class so that it remembers the number of sides it was instantiated with.

To do this, you would normally use an instance variable e.g. `@num_of_sides`, and set it equal to the `sides` param in the constructor, *after* you have checked for a valid input.

To read the number of sides you can either just return the value of `@num_of_sides` (alter your existing method to be much simpler, it doesn't need to take any parameters, and only needs to return the value you have stored, no tests/logic or randomness required), or you can use the short-cut `attr_reader :num_of_sides` which creates that method for you.

It would be worth reviewing any notes you have on Ruby instance variables, as this seems to be something you still need to get to grips with. Or you could take a look at this [Ruby Monk Primer on creating classes](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1/chapters/7-classes/lessons/40-building-your-own-class).